# How to restore Dejadup 14.04 backup in 16.04?

Tags: backup, deja-dup, 16.04

I backed up my 14.04 installation with dejadup on Amazon S3.

How can I restore it on a freshly installed Ubuntu 16.04, but not using it as backup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install the s3 backend for dej-dup:

```
sudo apt install deja-dup-backend-s3
```

Use `dconf-editor` under org -> gnome -> dejadup to copy the settings for the base installation. Also copy the keys for the S3 bucket and the encryption password. Open the deja-dup and start restore. Hint: Disable auto backup on both installations. Create a new bucket for backups for 16.04 to preserve the 14.04 backup!